# Seeing commits from other users in IntelliJ with Git and Bitbucket

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I'm using the bitbucket service to host my git repo, and I'm using Intellij 11 for my IDE.  However, I can't seem to see the commits from other team members to the bitbucket repository in Intellij's changes -> log tab without pulling down their changes.  Under the log tab I only see commits I've already pulled down.  I do see the commits from other developers once they are in my local repository.  But, I can't seem to see the commits I don't have in my local repo.

I've tried switching repos with the Branch drop downs to Remote -> origin/master, master, or All, but it never seems to change the content in the tab.  It always shows what I have on my local copy.  When I use the command line I can't use origin/master, but if simply use master I can see the changes.  Is this an IntelliJ bug?  A bitbucket bug?  Or pilot error?

Comment: "Under the log tab I only see commits I've already pulled down. I do see the commits from other developers once they are in my local repository." That's just the way git works.

Comment: Well no not exactly.  You make it sounds like I have no option here.  I think Adam's answer is the best which is I needed to do a git fetch to get the history information into my local branch before I could see what others were doing on the master branch.  After that I can do a normal pull to pull those changes down.  Not exactly as intuitive as SVN or even CVS, but I can live with that pattern of Fetch then Pull.

Comment: `git pull` runs `git fetch` then `git merge`. If you have already run `git fetch`, you don't really need to do `git pull`. You can do a `git merge` directly. Alternatively, you can just run `git pull` to begin with. Either way, you *must* fetch commits to your local repo because git does not allow you to read information directly from a remote repo. You *don't* have any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the changes to update your remote tracking branches first. Git will not show you what commits exist on the remote. It will only create that history to a viewable state after you have updated the remote tracking branches on your local repo.

Answer (score 2):

i do not know about Intellij, but with git you generally cannot see commits in remote repositories. The only thing you can do on remote repositories is fetch then and push to them, but all other operations are local.